# jQuery don't wait until scroll stop to run code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with my header that shows/hides on scroll. The code below is working nearly as intended with the only caveat being that it only runs once scrolling stops.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (top.location.pathname === '/') {

        var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
        var heroHeight = $("#home #hero").height();

        if (scrollHeight >= heroHeight) {
            $('.navbar').css("display", "block");
            $('.navbar').stop().animate({
                top: 0
            }, 200);
        } else {
            $('.navbar').stop().animate({
                top: "-50px"
            }, 200);
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas as to why this won't run once the height is greater than the height of `heroHeight`?

Comment: Try $(window).on("scroll", function(e)

Comment: Can you `console.log(scrollHeight)` and `console.log(heroHeight)`? Can't find anything wrong in the code.

Comment: @AJFMEDIA same effect, this is only happening when using the mac trackpad.